# Mobile - Scan text from camera, without taking a picture

Tags: android, ios, qr-code, augmented-reality, scanning

Is there a known API or way to **SCAN** the text from a card without actually manually saving (and uploading) the picture? (iOS and Android)

Then I would need to know if that API can determine the marquee within the camera that should be scanned.

I want a behaviour similar to the one of QR scanners, or Augmented Reality apps. Where the user just directs the camera and the action occurs.

I have printed cards with a Redeem code in Text, and including QR will need to change the current card production.

The **text** is inside a white box, which may make it easier to recognise:
 [image: redeem code]

Answer (score 2):

On iOS, you would use CIDetector with an AVCaptureSession. It can be used to process capture session output buffers as they come in from the camera without having to take a picture and provide text scanning.

For text detection, using CIDetector with CIDetectorTypeText will return areas that are likely to have text in them, but you would have to perform additional processing for Optical Character Recognition.

You could also use OpenCV for a not out of the box solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS

Usage:

```
    // Specify the image Tesseract should recognize on
tesseract.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_sample.jpg"] g8_blackAndWhite];

// Optional: Limit the area of the image Tesseract should recognize on to a rectangle
tesseract.rect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);

// Optional: Limit recognition time with a few seconds
tesseract.maximumRecognitionTime = 2.0;

// Start the recognition
[tesseract recognize];
```

Comment: I will try, thank you. Tesseract should be almost the same for Android right?